# Regexp search exact phrase in the string PHP

Tags: php, regex

i have an array containing some phrases:

```
$phrases = array(
  'phrase number one',
  'phrase number two',
  'phrase three',
  'phrase foo',
  'bar (foo 1.2.3)'
);
```

$text may contain part of phrase or exact phrase or phrase in the bbcode tags like this:

```
$text = '
  [b]phrase number one[/b] 
  [color="red"]phrase foo[/color]
  phrase three
  [b][color="red"]phrase foo[/color][/b]
  Lorem ipsum...
  [u][color="green"]phrase three[/color][/u]
  [url="http://example.com"]bar (foo 1.2.3)[/url]
  [url="http://example.com"][b]bar (foo 1)[/b][/url] dolor sit amet...
  phrase number two
';
```

i need to exclude that and search only exact phrase without bbcodes around it and replace: "phrase" => [other_bbcode]phrase[/other_bbcode]

```
foreach($phrases AS $phrase)
{
   $phrase = preg_quote($phrase, "#");
   if(preg_match('#(' . $phrase . ')+?#si', $text, $matches))
   {
      $text = preg_replace('#' . $matches[0] . '#i', '[other_bbcode]$matches[0][/other_bbcode]', $text);
   }
}
```

**phrase three** and **phrase number two** => replace

the rest text => stay as is

how to exclude phrases in bbcodes?

Thanks

Comment: What if the phrase is part of another wrapped in bbcode? Also, you would likely have to use some sort of look ahead/behind or a negative matching group like: `(?!not this)followed by this(?!then not this)`.

Comment: Something like: `(?!\[[^\]]+\])phrase number one(?!\[\/[^\]]+\])` would match `phrase number one` by itself or part of another string but not match if it has any `[anything]` (any text inside of square brackets) around it.

Comment: almost done, but... bbcode [url="link"] are parsed with phrase

[url="link"][url="link"]phrase[/url][/url] <=

how to exclude all bbcodes from search?

Comment: that does exclude all bbcode. The `\[[^\]]+\]` matches an open square bracket followed by one or more of any character that is not a closing square bracket followed by a closing square bracket. Perhaps the text inside of the bbcode doesn't match your phrase exactly or has a newline?

Comment: nevermind. I see the issue. Your phrase has parenthesis which are special characters in regex. You should also has the dot `.` which is a special character as well and could give you false positives. You should use `preg_quote()` around your `$phrase` variable when you are building the regex. `...atch('#(' . preg_quote($phrase, '#') . ')+?#si', $te...`

Comment: whist your regexp:
http://pastebin.com/5Kee1EQ5
result: http://savepic.su/4481417.png

Comment: The pattern matches exactly `[bbcode]Phrase[/bbcode]`. No variation. Not `[bbcode]Phrase, some other phrase[/bbcode]` (it doesn't matter what the tag is). If you need to find out if `Phrase` is inside of any open bbcode tag (even if `Phrase` is the leading/trailing part of the text inside of bbcode), this problem becomes infinitely harder and one not really suited for regular expressions alone.

Comment: mmm...
my question was: how to exclude all bbcodes around the phrase, and search only exact phrase without bbcodes
example of my code with your regexp, above
please, look screenshot to see result of code execution
regexp found "phrase one" in other "**phrase one** two three"
it's not a problem, i can filter this with "if($phrase == $matches[0])"
but some rest of the string parsed incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in three steps.

A. Isolate. Remove all formatted strings from the text, place them in a buffer and replace with some kind of placeholder:

```
$buf = [];

do {
    $text = preg_replace_callback('~\[(\w+).+?\[/\1\]~', function($m) use(&$buf) {
        $buf []= $m[0];
        return '@' . (count($buf) - 1) . '@';
    }, $text, -1, $count);
} while($count);
```

B. Replace. Construct a regex from the phrases array and replace it in the "clean" text:

```
$re = implode('|', array_map(function($x) {
    return '(' . preg_quote($x, '~') . ')';
}, $phrases));

$text = preg_replace("~$re~", '[new]$0[/new]', $text);
```

C. De-isolate. Replace placeholders created on step A with their values from the buffer:

```
do {
    $text = preg_replace_callback('~@(\d+)@~', function($m) use($buf) {
        return $buf[$m[1]];
    }, $text, -1, $count);
} while($count);
```

Another (and more robust in the long run) option is to convert bbcodes to xml and use DOM methods to walk the tree and manipulate its nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your example
but i have PHP 5.2.6 and this code doesn't work

Comment: @krez: bad luck for you then ;(

Comment: On PHP 5.4.7 your code works perfect!
thanks!
how to rewrite this code to work on php 5.2.x?

Comment: @krez: rewrite callbacks to normal named functions, and use `preg_replace_callback(..., 'yourFunctionName',...)`. The `$buf` variable must be global.